# How to fix gross prices with Magento CE 1.8.1

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, tax

we have the problem that with the new EU guideline for salestaxes, the product gross prices have to be fixed!

We have 3 different tax rates, but every customer should pay the same gross price!

Magento only needs to show the tax rate in the order overview and invoice, but should not calculate a new price based on the 3 different tax rates.(Like it is when I choose the backend option "Tax calculation based on" = "billing address")

Just found out that there is an extention for Magento 1.7 and older and that there is a backend option in Magento 1.9 called "Cross-Border Price Consistency"to handle the problem.

But I need a solution for Magento 1.8.1

Any idea?

Comment: Have you looked into updating your Magento installation?